# How to compare one array element with all others array elements in a for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got a task to find which circle intersects with the most other circles.

I have the x-coordinates, y-coordinates, and the radii of many different circles. I've put x-coordinates into array `X[]`, y-coordinates into `Y[]` and radius into `R[]`. I've also found the way to check if one circle intersects with another, shown below.

I know that two FOR loops should be used,but I can't seem to find the way,so that the loop compares one element to all other elements in the array,then compares another element to all other elements and etc. Maybe someone knows the way?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is the number of circles  
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)  
    { 
        // More code here...
    }
}
```

To check if the circle `i` intersects with circle `i+1`, my `if` evaluates:

```
if (Distance (n, X, Y,i ) < (Radius[i] + Radius[i+1])) // i is the index of the element
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is the number of circles
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
To check if the circle intersects my IF is : if (Distance (n, X, Y,i ) < (Radius[i] + Radius[i+1]))  // i is the index of the element

Comment: First of all what have you tried ? Can you show us? Second a good way to find if two circles intersect is by calculating the difference of the centers and then check if the sum of both circle radius are greater than the distance. If the distance is greater than the sum of radius, circles do not intersect.

Comment: The function that that finds the distance is : distance = sqrt(pow((A[index+1] - A[index]), 2) + pow((B[index+1] - B[index]), 2)); And the function that should find if the circle intersects and which circle intersects the most :  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
   if (Distance(X, Y, i) < (Radius[i] + Radius[i + 1]))

Comment: I know computers are fast, but would you solve this problem by hand by comparing points on all the circles?  Or would you just use good old basic geometry?  If you have n circles, know there radii, know the position of their respective centers, why would you want to compare the points on each and every circle?

Comment: @feco:  I have copied the code from your first commented into your question.  Please put the code from your other comments into your question.  Look at the difference between code in a comment and code in the question.  The code in the question is more readable.

Comment: Sorry, I'am new here. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I only need to find a way how to compare f.e. first array element with all other elements,then the second array element with all the other elements and etc. Because if using a standard FOR loop,it just compares first element with the second element,then the second element with the third element and so on..

Comment: Look at your code in the question.  What purpose would index `j` serve?  In other words, you wrote a nested loop, but your code refuses to take advantage of the inner loop.  Your `Distance` calculation doesn't use `Radius[ j ]` at all.

Comment: It's just for the model, still trying to think of an idea how would it serve me. Yes, you're right my functions don't use index  j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, there are two questions being asked simultaneously. First question is how to compare each element of one array to all elements of second array. Second question is how to find the maximum amount of times a condition has been met. Furthermore, the condition depends on the comparison of an element in the first array with the elements of the second array.

```
int max = 0;
int n = 9;                        // n will probably be the size of your arrays
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    int times_condition_met = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if ( condition == true )  // Checking a condition/making a comparison.
        {
           times_condition_met++; // Increment the  number of times the condition is met.
        }
    }

    if (times_condition_met > max)
    {
        // Update the max and other information you're interested in.
        // I.e. this is where you want to save the information regarding
        // the index of your circles.
    }

}
```

Essentially, I believe your task is requiring you two keep track of some sort of statistic while doing the comparisons between your two arrays. In order to do so, you have to add some extra code into the nested-for loops that does this tracking.

Comment: Maybe i've stated my question a bit wrong. I want the FOR loop to pick the first circle and then check with how many circles does it intersect and show me the number,then take the second circle and check with how many circles does it intersect and so on. And after these calculations are done it would need to find the biggest value (the number of circles it intersects) and that it would show me the index of that circle (which intersects with the most other circles).

Comment: The FOR loop takes the first circle and then starts checking if it intersects with the second circle,third circle,fourth circle and in the end it shows me the number of how many circles does it intersect with.

Comment: Okay. In that case, there are some missing components that you will want to consider:

1.) You will need to find a way to count the number of times that some circle intersects with the other ones.
2.) You will need to find a way to store the current maximum that you have calculated.
3.) You will also need to find a way to update this maximum.

Comment: I was thinking about an idea of putting the numbers I get (how many times some circle intersects with the other ones) into an array and then finding the maximum. Dno tho,it could be too difficult . Maybe you have some ideas of doing the parts you mentioned ?

Comment: Your idea is plausible as well. If you're interested in saving that information, you could put the number of times a circle intersects into an array, which you could play around with later. I've edited my answer to give you an idea of how to find the max, but it does not save the information regarding the other circles.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I really appreciate that. But i'am still kinda stuck. So how do I identify which circle is being checked in the FOR loop (or does the index i show it)? And maybe you could show how should the code should look if I would like to see like : the index of circle and then how many circles it intersects with and so on.

Comment: Try running this piece of code: http://pastebin.com/N9YswWFk. This should tell you how `i` and `j` are being incremented/tracked. For your code, `i` and `j` should be used as indices, to access the different parts of your arrays.

Comment: I think I understand your previous comment/question about "identify[ing] which circle is being checked". When you're inside the `j` loop, `i` is being held at some single value, while `j` increments. So while you're in that loop, circle `i` is being compared to circle `j = 0`, then circle `j = 1`, then circle `j = 2`, etc. Does that help?

Comment: Btw, I'am supposed to use  i < n< and j < n instead of  i < 10 < and  j < 10  , right ? So the program would be more useful?

Comment: Yes, `n` would make more sense in your case, since you'll want to check all `n` of your circles, whose information is stored in your different arrays. I used a constant (`9`) because I did not quite understand the question at the time. [:

Comment: Oh I see now. Tried running that piece of code which shows all of the i and j ,it helped me to understand your idea better.

Comment: So if the (times_condition_met > max) then (max = max + times_condition_met) ?

Comment: You have the right idea, but because I've written the code incorrectly ]: Let me edit me answer again, and see if you can find an even better way to update the max. [:

Comment: Btw, I replaced (condition) with (if (Distance(X, Y, i) < (Radius[i] + Radius[i + 1]) == true)) is that the right way to use it ?

Comment: It is possible for that to work, but it might not for your particular problem. Notice that when `i = n`, `Radius[i + 1]` will be outside of the array! We need to fix this........ In our head, we are comparing circle `i` with circle `j`, not circle `i` with circle `i + 1`. Think about that [: You might also need to modify the beginning of the `j` for-loop, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes,man! Haha,just thought about that and changed i+1 to j! Check out my code http://pastebin.com/sUGDzqJa

Comment: Great, you're almost there [: I've changed the code a bit, so make sure your max is updating correctly in this new setup. P.S. I won't be changing the answer anymore, because I think the community would prefer an answer that is easy to understand/not too specific to your problem.

Comment: I just placed the int times_condition_met = 0; line inside the first FOR loop. Where should I write the cout line ? After the second FOR loop? So it should look like std :: cout << i ( the index of circle) << " circle intersects with " << times_condition_met << " other circles." << endl;

Comment: Just to be more explicit, I don't think that `(times_condition_met > max) then (max = max + times_condition_met)` will work quite the way you want it to. If `times_condition_met > max`, you can simply set `max = times_condition_met`. Adding it might make a very big max!

Comment: If you do manage to get your code to work from my help, I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer as well [:

Comment: I've just tried it. But the results seems to be wrong. http://pastebin.com/PHirDckb check it out. There's the full code : http://pastebin.com/txrsDv0t Edit : I've changed the second FOR loop,i've replaced the i < j with i < j - 1 ,the results seem to be correct now ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what results you are expecting. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Only 8 circles are given in the file,so one circle can't intersect with 9 circles. That's why I thought the results were wrong,i'll check the results now with the j < n-1 in the second FOR loop

Comment: My guess is that it's checking if a circle is intersecting with itself i.e. at some point `i = j`. Try modifying your `j` loop [:

Comment: Yes,I did exactly that. I've changed the j loop, so it's now for ( int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) the results are now more close to the correct ones,but it still looks weird,since it shows that some circle intersects with 8 circles,when 8 circles are given overall.

Comment: Notice that the condition `n-1` simply evaluates to some constant. However, when we're doing our comparisons, we need the value of `j` to somehow be dependent on the value of `i`. More precisely, `j` should not equal `i`. You'll need to somehow change the `j < n - 1` to something that depends on the value of `i`, while still hitting the remaining indices.

Comment: Here's a hint: Let's say that we've already went through the loop with `i = 0`, meaning we've compared the first circle with all of the other circles. We continue along, and at some point, `i = 1`. Do we still need to compare circle 1 with circle 0, if we did that earlier? We only really need compare circle 1 with circles 2, 3, 4, ... `n`. How about when `i = 2'?

Comment: Maybe changing it to for ( int j = 0; j != i; i++) is the right solution ? Or that's out of question?

Comment: I will leave the rest to you. I would feel bad for taking away a good learning experience by providing you the answer. You're almost there though [:

Comment: Gotta get it done for tomorrow.. :D And yet  it shows the wrong results,gonna be a long night seems like ^^